# Would the central fringe in the Double Slit Experiment be less populated if we negatively charge the spot between the two slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, charge, interference, double-slit-experiment

Would the the interference pattern in the Double slit Experiment with electrons look different if we make the point between slits charged? Would the patterns elongate or would the distribution among fringes be different if we do so? Would this help understand how the electron passes through the slits?

Answer (score 2):

I did this experiment.
I used a razor blade to create a double slit in a mirror. Here’s a video of that process: Make a Double Slit https://youtu.be/9wBi8Xb4OJg
I then used the razor to isolate a circuit in the mirror's silver backing that would allow me to send voltage directly through the thin silver strip between the slits. The voltage I used was a fairly high voltage from a piezoelectric “clicker” lighter. I noticed no change to the interference pattern. Maybe a different voltage or more current would make a difference. Give it a try.

Comment: you wrote "noticed no change to the interference pattern" but I think your video shows correctly elongation of the "orders" as you tilt the slits relative to the beam.

Comment: @hyportnex yes, rotating the mirror does effect the pattern. I was responding to the question regarding voltage through the slit.

Comment: . I suspect that if we charge negatively the spot between the slits the central fringe on the screen would be less populated and the lateral ones more polulated.... Maybe this could be wrong...

Comment: @KrešimirBradvica oops yes my experiment was with photons

Comment: Your video shows only photons?